# OpenLayers 3 capturing various click events

Tags: openlayers, events

I would like my KML layer in OpenLayers 3 (OL3) to respond to different types of click events.

I have a single click method working nicely. But how do I get it working for "shift-clicks" "double clicks" etc?

```
 map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {                         
   var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
     function(feature, layer) {
     // do stuff here with feature
     return [feature, layer];                                  
   });                                                         
 });
```

[This](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/select-features.html) was a good start, but I can't quite put the OL3 API documentation together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ah ok `dblclick` is the answer

```
// set mode to current mode of double clicked feature                       
map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
  console.log('doubled');
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature, layer) {
      // do stuff here
    });
});
```

and `evt.originalEvent.altKey`, `evt.originalEvent.ctrlKey`, `evt.originalEvent.metaKey`, `evt.originalEvent.shitKey` are all availabe within the handler!

Answer (score 3):

Get clicked XY coordinates in ol3

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
var coordinates = evt.coordinate;
alert(coordinates);
});
```

Comment: Can I get latitude and longitude here?

Comment: What if you want to get coordinates of two same event (such as a mouse 'click') but separated in time in different variable without updating the coordinates of the first event?